# How to Turn Standard Web Server into GIS Capable?

Tags: web-service

I have been pointed to help our IT dept to embeded GIS ability in our custom ERP system. The server that host the system has the following standard settings : Apache, PHP, MySQL and JavaScript. The problem is our IT guys not allowed me in "messing" with their system, so to suggesting installing mapserver or geoserver or other gis capable server is highly restricted.

Their current solution is converting our native mapinfo tab files into svg files. IMHO this solution will not answered the management needs.

I am thinking to use pure openlayers, another problem is the only way to read our tab files is by convert them into geojson.

The concept on their mind is all of GIS data is inserted into MySQL, I've heard about MySQL-GIS but I don't know how the plugin is supported today.

Basicly I don't do the job, I just give them the right direction, but with this limitation I can't figure out how to achieve this.

So to cleared out my question is, I have a standard Apache, PHP, MySQL and JavaScript system, I'm hoping my GIS data is read and write from or to MySQL. How can I turn that standard web system into GIS capable system without changing any setting on my server? OpenLayers are welcome.

Any suggestion are most welcome.

Regards,
Zery

Comment: You might get more responses if you accept some of the answers first on some of your other questions.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 3):

You should begin with the type of data to be stored and retrieved.  Vector, polygon and point data can be stored directly into a mysql database and returned.  Is all of the data projected in the same coordinate system?  What format will your users be retrieving data?

My recommendation would be to run geoserver or mapserver separately of your main server, store your data in the existing mysql (or Postgresql) and point the geoserver/mapserver to that storage.

@zery If you are able, install Postgresql with PostGIS (it's easy to install) to run concurrently with MySQL.  Store your GIS data in PostGIS and link/query the tabular data needed that is already stored in MySQL.

Comment: We don't have other server, so we have to stick with this only we've got. We still considering any possibilities to make it works. MySQL spatial extensions is our big hopes, unfortunately we have to leave it behind.

Comment: @Zery MySQL spatial support is very limited. You'd be better off switching to PostGreSQL and PostGIS.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm very aware of postgis, I have give them that options also, still the answers is no add or changing on the server. So we have comes up with a solution, using ogr2ogr and mapbasic we translate the mapinfo files to geojson, and we use openlayers to map it. Thanks.